# How can I share code between a codenameone project and a regular java project?

Tags: java, json, codenameone

I have a codenameone project that is exchanging json messages via websockets with a server implemented in java.

The json messages are mapped to pojos on both sides.

I would like to define the pojos only once and reuse them on both sides.

Is there a simple way to do this ? Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the best way to do this is to keep your POJOs in a third project, and create a build script to "copy" them into each project that uses them.

If you would rather copy them as "binaries" rather than source, you could adjust your build script to compile them into a cn1lib and jar, copy the jar to the server classpath (or into maven), and copy the cn1lib into the client libs.